# Django context processor throw error on redirect

Tags: python, django, django-context

I'm using the following context processor to pass context to all my pages, except when the user is not logged in which case it takes him to the login page :

```
from django.conf import settings
from .models import foo
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def globalVar(request):
    if not request.session.get('user_id') is None:
        return {"foo": foo}
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

But the redirect causes an exception for which i didn't find a fix :
`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required`

Am i not looking in the right place, or is there a way to replace redirect by something else ?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that the problem is in the name argument in the `url` or `path`

Comment: You're likely to pass the `name` as a positional argument in the position of the `context`, use `name='login'` in the urlpattern you have and it should work fine.

Comment: you mean replace `'login'` by `'name='login'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply return a redirect from a context processor, since context processors need to return a dict of context variables.

If you really need this functionality in a context processor, you would need to

- define a custom exception class (that e.g. wraps the response)
- raise such an exception from the context processor (since you can't return a non-dictionary)
- catch the custom exception in a Django middleware, unwrap the response and return it

(as an aside, I've written a package that does that – [`django-safespace`](https://github.com/valohai/django-safespace))

Instead, if you can, use the [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator (or CBV mixin – see the linked documentation) to make your entire view logged-in-user only.

Comment: can you give an example please @AKX

Comment: Or can you please write, How I can render a form in Context processor whenever I am trying to submit it? Or on refresh, it is submitting again and again. Can I render a message from a context processor?

Comment: @ash You can return a form object from a context processor if you need to. I wouldn't use a context processor to manipulate request messages, it sounds like quite the hairy side effect.

Comment: i am creating a footer subscribe form

Comment: so and i am new to django

Comment: Right. You can use a template tag or context processor to render one, but the comments here aren't the right place for questions. Ask a question detailing your particular problem.

Comment: remember i asked alredy you commented too

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue lately. In a class-based view, method `get_context_data`, I needed to raise an Exception if certain conditions were not met, and trigger a redirect (while showing an error message using django.messages).

I got this error:

```
TypeError: context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect.
```

I solved it

- letting the `get_context_data` method free to raise the error (not catching it here)
- patching the view dispatch method like this:

```
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            # use django message to show the error
            messages.error(self.request, message=e)
            # here redirect does work
            return redirect(reverse(...))
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: The above answer assumed something else so I've deleted and replaced with an elaboration of why returning redirect doesn't work in case you want to understand

```
context = {}
redirect = redirect('login')
context.update(redirect)
```

This should cause the same error you're getting. Got the idea?

Comment: I don't really understand where you are suggesting me to put that, and what should i replace the `...` with ?

Comment: Unfortunately you hit the 1% – this problem has nothing to do with the URL patterns.

Comment: Yea mb, I'll explain what happens anyway